# Using HAAR cascade can I detect Personal protective equipment (PPE's) if yes which HAAR file would be used among face eye upper body lower body etc

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I m a beginner so I wanted to know the details I have asked in my problem statement
I m bit confused because I haven't used HAAR before so I wanted to know which HAAR XML file would be used in PPE detection so that I can complete my task on time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just use AI. haar cascades are obsolete.